# Redirection from http to https is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

this is the command i use in my .htaccess file and when i type arion-software.co.uk it does not properly redirects.
any idea?

Comment: I'm curious if any of those answers fit your query ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it works for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

And this is where I got it from: [redirect http to https](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/)

EDIT: the link provides examples to your domain with or without the "www." subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

There you go, http to https rewrite:

```
## Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```